# Liferay 7 : How to create custom email template in liferay 7?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

How to create custom email template in liferay 7.

**Use Case :** I want to send email with custom template because my newsletter template design is fix but there is some dynamic content Which I want to include dynamically in that template.

**Liferay Version : liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga5**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on which scenario do you want to trigger email for and are you able to create simple template without css?

Comment: Thanks Shivam, I am not able to create simple email template in Liferay 7. I want to add some dynamic content in predefine custom email template.

Comment: still not enough: Please edit your question (not comment) to include: a usecase (are you sending a custom mail, or do you need to extend an existing template?) What did you try so far, and how exactly did it not work? "not able to" signals a question that is too broad for Stackoverflow. Narrow it down as much as you can. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask